# Column names Missing when stored in Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy data from on-premises sql server to Azure blob, i am able to successfully copy data into Azure blob storage but the column names are missing in the .csv file that we tried storing in the container of azure blob storage.

Kindly let me know is there any ways to add column names in Azure blob storage.

Comment: Blobs don't have *columns* - they are just... blobs, and you can store anything you want - there's no formatting. But you tagged this as [tag:azure-data-factory] - is that what you're using to move data to blob storage? You should edit your question to show what, exactly, you're doing. As your question is written, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, We are using Azure Data factory to copy data from On premise sql server into azure blob storage, the data gets copied into blob storage but it doesnt have any column names in it..

Comment: Ok great: 1) edit your question, don't bury details in comments. 2) this isn't a blob issue - this is specifically related to the export from azure data factory (as I stated before: blobs have no concept whatsoever of columns - they are just objects).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is "blobWriterAddHeader," by default this is false. It is a property on the sink portion of the copy activity for a blobsink.

```
{
"name": "Pipeline",
"properties": {
    "description": "",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select id, name from employees"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "BlobSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00",
                    "blobWriterAddHeader": true
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "input"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "output"
                }
            ],
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "pipeline_name",
            "description": "copy activity"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2016-09-06T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2016-09-06T23:59:59Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/) search the page for "blobWriterAddHeader"

Hope this helps.